# How to get the number of registers by month and date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have rows of user data. I store the createDate, which is the timestamp in milliseconds when the user registered. I want to get the total number of registrations per month. When I try to do that, I don't get any rows returned. Here's the query I'm using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE YEAR(createDate) = 2023 GROUP BY MONTH(createDate)
```

createDate is BIGINT and is the date in milliseconds

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `createDate` column is defined as `TIMESTAMP(3)`, to get millisecond resolution. [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) comes in handy here.

Try this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), LAST_DAY(createDate) month_ending
  FROM users
 WHERE createDate >= '2023-01-01' 
   AND createDate <  '2024-01-01'
 GROUP BY LAST_DAY(createDate)
```

The date range test I use for getting the dates in a single year is [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). That is, it can be accelerated by an index on `createDate`, where `YEAR(createDate)` cannot be.

This approach generates a useful result set if you run it on a multi-year date range.

But, if your result set is empty (has no rows), the result set from this query will be too. That might mean:

- your table has no dates in that range, or
- your `createDate` data type is something other than TIMESTAMP or DATETIME. (You didn't show us the table definition.)

Comment: Hi createDate is BIGINT - date in milliseconds. Your query doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to convert to/from unix time:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), LAST_DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(createDate/1000)) month_ending
  FROM users
 WHERE createDate >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2023-01-01') * 1000
   AND createDate <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2024-01-01') * 1000
 GROUP BY month_ending
```